# Origen y etimología de modorra

Tags: etimología, vocabulario-médico

El sustantivo modorro o modorra (como sinónimo de enfermedad acompañada de pereza o sueño pesado) ya aparece en los primeros diccionarios del español e incluso es mencionada por Nebrija en su diccionario y por Colón en su Diario de Indias, lo que da a entender que es una palabra con unos cuantos años en el idioma. Sin embargo, la RAE deja el origen como origen incierto.

En etimologías de Chile se le da un [posible origen vasco o latino](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?modorra), pero quisiera saber que tan probables son esos orígenes y si hay registros previos de finales del siglo XV que confirmen que ya se conocía la palabra en español.

Comment: Lo de hacerse tronco me parece bien -- http://etimologias.dechile.net/?modorra

Comment: @Charo veo que estás haciendo ediciones pequeñas a publicaciones antiguas. Sugiero que aproveches también para mejorar títulos, etiquetar con precisión, etc. En concreto, [el tema de las etiquetas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) lo llevamos bastante flojo en esta comunidad e iría bien ir ganando consistencia en su uso

Comment: OK, @fedorqui'SOstopharming': intentaré hacer lo que buenamente pueda.

Comment: @Charo gracias! Tus mejoras siempre son más que bienvenidas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según [An Etymological Dictionary of the Romance Languages](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6lPuAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA304&lpg=PA304&dq=modorra%20etymology&source=bl&ots=QOcZwALrA1&sig=ACfU3U0U8urwmNolDXZxm1TqIovxxpnmTg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihgIm_lf7jAhU6QUEAHRWiBVYQ6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=modorra%20etymology&f=false), modorra viene del vasco *modorra*, tocón de un árbol.

En [How Spanish Grew](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=InGYUy0Vu6gC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=basque%20modorra&source=bl&ots=M-7TWj7qi1&sig=ACfU3U03FgdV0rLpsn5lv0BnHwzbzz2FkA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKpb_elf7jAhVTT8AKHQ8nBfIQ6AEwEnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=basque%20modorra&f=false) de Robert K. Spaulding se puede encontrar (traducción propia):

> Las palabras heredadas por el español de los tiempos pre-románicos no son numerosas. La mayoría, sino todas, han sido cuestionadas, y como muchas de ellas, como izquierdo y toca, pueden relacionarse con términos Vascos modernos. Entre las palabras que son consideradas anteriores a los romanos  están [...]; y muchas palabras que terminan en *rro*, *rra*: *becerro, bizarro, cachorro*,... La etimología de *chorro, cotorra, modorra, pachorra* [...] es dudosa pero la extensión del sufijo es obvia.

En este otro [sitio](http://euskerarenjatorria.eus/?lang=en&paged=3&lang=en) también se menciona la relación entre la palabra y el vasco:

> modorra, (Delika, Alava) “*firewood pruned from trees*”, (Monalau) “*coppice stool*”